# What does "So Car" mean in 19th century?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the book *South Carolina Goes to War, 1860-1865*,there is a sentence:

> I am amused at the coolness with which the Southern States offer to march to the assistance of **So Car**—they must be sleeping in fancied security—why in less than a year it is more than likely that the whole South will be in a blaze from one end to the other.

I'm translating a book quoted this sentence. But what is "So Car" in this context?

Comment: Perhaps **So**uth **Car**olina?  In the words of Homer Simpson, "D'oh!"  :-)

Comment: Where I live in California, we say *NorCal* and *SoCal*, which I guess is kind of similar :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the author refers to So Car, they are referring to Southern Carolina, one of the southern states. "Southern" is often abbreviated as "So" or "So." and Carolina can be abbreviated "So Car", or more often now as "SC" or "S.C."